# MAAS is unable to detect subnets

Tags: networking, juju, maas

I have created fresh maas setup with version 2.2.1-6078-g2a6d9. 
It's unable to detect subnets.

Errors from maas.log:

Jul 17 07:08:44 pranita_maas maas.dhcp.probe: [error] Can't initiate DHCP probe; no RPC connection to region.
Jul 17 07:08:44 pranita_maas maas.boot_image_download_service: [error] Can't initiate image download, no RPC connection to region.
Jul 17 07:08:59 pranita_maas maas.service_monitor_service: [error] Can't update service statuses, no RPC connection to region.
Jul 17 07:09:59 pranita_maas maas.service_monitor_service: [error] Can't update service statuses, no RPC connection to region.
Jul 17 07:10:24 pranita_maas maas.start-up: [warn] Error during start-up; pausing for 3 seconds.
Jul 17 07:10:24 pranita_maas maas.networks.monitor: [info] Networks monitoring service: Process ID 13543 assumed responsibility.
Jul 17 07:10:24 pranita_maas maas.start-up: [warn] Error during start-up; pausing for 3 seconds.
Jul 17 07:10:24 pranita_maas maas.service_monitor: [info] Service 'maas-proxy' is not on, it will be started.
Jul 17 07:10:24 pranita_maas maas.start-up: [warn] Error during start-up; pausing for 3 seconds.
Jul 17 07:10:24 pranita_maas maas.start-up: [warn] Error during start-up; pausing for 3 seconds.
Jul 17 07:10:24 pranita_maas maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/

Answer (score 1):

This issue was due to low configuration of VM.
I updated machine's config to  12GB RAM and 4 VCPUs and MAAS is able to detect subnets.